# What are the best/popular libraries for developing CLI apps/scripts?

Tags: multithreading, posix, php, pcntl

Many of the component libraries and toolkits I'm familiar with lack CLI-specific libraries (zend, kohana, etc..). Are there any libraries/tools that are designed specifically for developing CLI application (such as an abstraction of php's multi-threading library, pcntl/posix)?

Comment: When you say CLI are you referring to Microsoft .NET?  Common Language Infrstructure?  Or Command Line Interface?

Comment: @Aaron : in a PHP-related context, CLI means Command Line Interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ncurses is compatible with PHP, and is used to develop a wide number of CLI applications in many different languages.

More info:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/1083

Answer (score 1):

I've used [**PEAR package Console_CommandLine**](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_CommandLine) and was very satisfied. I may not fulfill all you requirements though, but it's worth giving it a look.

It helps parsing the input (arguments, options, sub-commands, etc...) and build basic functionnalities (usage, version, ...).